# Cassandra read calls failing with com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadFailureException

Tags: cassandra

In one of our single node Cassadra deployment, there's this table schema:

```
CREATE table CTS_SVC_PT_INT_READ (
    svc_pt_id bigint,
    meas_type_id bigint,
    value double,
    flags bigint,
    read_time timestamp,
    last_upd_time timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (svc_pt_id, meas_type_id, read_time)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (meas_type_id ASC, read_time DESC)
AND compaction = {
    'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.DateTieredCompactionStrategy',
    'timestamp_resolution': 'MILLISECONDS',
    'base_time_seconds': '3600',
    'max_sstable_age_days': '365'
};
```

While querying `select distinct svc_pt_id from cts.CTS_SVC_PT_INT_READ`  through the Java client, it's failing with the exception:

```
select distinct svc_pt_id from  cts.CTS_SVC_PT_INT_READ com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadFailureException: Cassandra failure during read query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded, 1 failed)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadFailureException: Cassandra failure during read query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded, 1 failed)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:299)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:286)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeToObservableFuture$ToObservableFuture.call(OnSubscribeToObservableFuture.java:74)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeToObservableFuture$ToObservableFuture.call(OnSubscribeToObservableFuture.java:43)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8314)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:94)
at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadFailureException: Cassandra failure during read query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded, 1 failed)
at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadFailureException.copy(ReadFailureException.java:95)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:128)
at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.onSet(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:179)
at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:184)
at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.access$2500(RequestHandler.java:43)
at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:798)
at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.onSet(RequestHandler.java:617)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:1005)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:928)
at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:318)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:304)
at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:318)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:304)
at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:318)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:304)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:354)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:244)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:318)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:304)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112)
... 1 more
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadFailureException: Cassandra failure during read query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded, 1 failed)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error$1.decode(Responses.java:76)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error$1.decode(Responses.java:37)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Message$ProtocolDecoder.decode(Message.java:266)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Message$ProtocolDecoder.decode(Message.java:246)
at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:89)
... 15 more
```

I see the same error if I issue this cql command through cqlsh. Is it due to a ReadTimeOut issue or something else?

Answer (score 1):

"ReadFailureException: Cassandra failure ... 0 replica responded, 1 failed)" indicates a failure, not a timeout. You might learn something further by looking at the cassandra log on the server.

Comment: Thanks Adam for your feedback. I went through logs not much info. AssertionFailure error is coming from some other thread not sure if they are related. Any feedbak is aprreciated. Thank you                                                                                       DEBUG [SharedPool-Worker-8] 2016-08-30 19:52:04,230 ReadCallback.java:126 - Failed; received 0 of 1 responses
WARN  [SharedPool-Worker-9] 2016-08-30 19:52:04,231 AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:169 - Uncaught exception on thread Thread[SharedPool-Worker-9,5,main]: {}
java.lang.AssertionError: null
 at org.a

Comment: at org.apache.cassandra.db.Slice$Bound.create(Slice.java:365) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.jar:3.3]
 at org.apache.cassandra.db.Slice$Bound$Serializer.deserializeValues(Slice.java:553) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.jar:3.3]
 at org.apache.cassandra

Comment: It sounds like this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11158